# Checking whether ANY url is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

I am new to Javascript as well as Jquery , but can not figure out what I am doing wrong. I just want to check if the user is on any of 3 URLs. I just want to check if the user is on either the ABOUT US, MEMSTAFF TEAM or CAREERS sections. That is it. I thought that if I just used the OR (||) operator, this should work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// Check if any of these relative URLS are true
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/about-us" || "/memstaff-team" || "/careers") > -1) {
// Alert me if I am in one of the MAIN sections
alert("Your are in one of the MAIN sections");
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: The value of the expression `"/about-us" || "/memstaff-team" || "/careers"` is simply `"/about-us"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("/about-us" || "/memstaff-team" || "/careers") > -1)
```

is equivalent to doing

```
temp = "/about-us" || "/memstaff-team" || "/careers";
if (window.location.href.indexOf(temp) > -1)
```

Since the `||` operator just returns the first truthy value, it's effectively doing `temp = "/about-us"` and just testing for that. "OR" expressions aren't automatically distributed, you need to do it explicitly.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("/about-us") > -1 ||
    window.location.href.indexOf("/memstaff-team") > -1 || 
    window.location.href.indexOf("/careers") > -1)
```

But a simpler way is to use a regular expression:

```
if (window.location.href.match(/\/(about-us|memstaff-team|careers)/))
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I figured that is was just testing the first value, but did not know how to construct it properly. Thanks Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it:

```
const urls = ["/about-us", "/memstaff-team", "/careers"];
if (urls.some(url => window.location.href.indexOf(url)  > -1)) { 
   alert("...");
}
```